# Multivariate Elastic Net with glmnet

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection, glmnet, elastic-net

I am using *glmnet* package for elastic net. 
I'd like to perform variable selection and classification on a 50x41 data set with 3 response variables (one continuous and two categorical), but I have not found any method to perform it. Is that possible? Or should I use another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you not use `glmnet`?

Take a look at [this nice overview of the package](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html).  Under the **Linear Regression** heading, go to **Multiresponse Gaussian Family**.  This is the method you are likely looking to use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have two categorical variables and a continuous variable. Thank you for the link. I missed someway during my search, I'll study it.

Comment: @schrodingercat was this help what you were looking for?

Comment: unfortunately not for my current analysis. If I understood correctly, multiresponse gaussian family is only for numerical variables. I have at least one continuous and one categorical variable.

Comment: Then you may either want to (1) factorize your categorical variables, or (2) use a linear mixed model (not `glmnet`)